# This.blur() doesn't work for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, blur

I want to remove the focus after clicking a button[type=button]. To accomplish this I am using:

```
<button type="button" onfocus="this.blur();">Click here</button>
```

This works flawless on laptop and pc, but doesn't work for mobile devices. Is there anyone who knows how to remove the focus for mobile?

Comment: just find another element and apply `focus()` on it?

Comment: If you want to remove focus after clicking, why not use the click event?

Comment: That doesn't work either

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your button element:
    style="outline:none;-moz-outline:none" hidefocus="true"